# Using registers in Miips assembly language

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

I'm trying to understand how miips instructions work, and looking at the `bne` instruction. I think I understand it at a high level, I just have a few questions.

For example, let's say I use the command `bne $R0, $R10, X`. this is the same as saying if `$R0` does not equal `$R10`, jump to address `X` (where address `X` is calculated as `PC+4+4*X`, and `X` is some integer).

- When you look at a standard register table (I found several on Google that were identical, I assumed they are standard), there are 31 registers. So when you specify a value for `X`, does that mean `X` is limited to values such that 4*`X` < 31? (or more restricted since several registers in the range 0-31 are reserved for system use?), or is that going to be an address in memory, and not a register?
- I know that if I use `$t0-$t7` I am using registers 8-15, and `$s0-$s7` uses registers 17-23, but where is `$R0-$Rk` (for some integer k<32, I assume) located? Is that the same 32 registers I would use for `$t0, $s5`, etc? For example, are `$R10`, register 10, and `$t2` the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you look at a standard register table (I found several on Google that were identical, I assumed they are standard), there are 31 registers.

This is not exactly correct. There are 32 general-purpose registers on MIPS, counting `r0`, as well as a number of special-purpose registers such as `pc`, `lo` and `hi`, and floating-point registers.

> So when you specify a value for `X`, does that mean `X` is limited to values such that 4*`X` < 31? (or more restricted since several registers in the range 0-31 are reserved for system use?), or is that going to be an address in memory, and not a register?

Neither. The value for `X` is specified as a constant within the instruction. The encoding looks like:

```
BNE: 0001 01ss ssst tttt  iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

The encoding for this instruction begins with a 6-bit header (`000101`), uses 5 bits for each of the source and destination registers (`s` and `t`), and uses the remaining 16 bits of the instruction for a signed 16-bit offset (`i`). This offset is treated as a count of instructions relative to the next PC - as a result, you can jump up to 64 KB in each direction.

> I know that if I use `$t0-$t7` I am using registers 8-15, and `$s0-$s7` uses registers 17-23, but where is `$R0-$Rk` (for some integer k<32, I assume) located? Is that the same 32 registers I would use for `$t0, $s5`, etc? For example, are `$R10`, register 10, and `$t2` the same thing?

Yes — some MIPS general-purpose registers have multiple names. `r10` and "register 10" both refer to the register by its location, whereas `t2` refers to it by its conventional use as a **T**emporary register.

Comment: One more question came to mind. When the instruction is fetched, that is when the opcode is used, correct?

Comment: Revised*: When the instruction is fetched, that is when the opcode is loaded into the Instruction Register, correct?